# Insert Data to Table with Some of Data is from Another Table

Tags: oracle

I'm new on oracle and sql in general and want to ask something. So let's say I have data like this on txt data:

| Agt Code | Sales |
| --- | --- |
| 000001 | 20,000 |
| 000002 | 25,000 |

And I want to insert that into a table (sales_master) that have structure like this

**| Agt Code | Agt Name | Job | Sales |**

And for the Agt Name and Job information is already on another table (agt_info) on DB like this:

| Agt Code | Agt Name | Job |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 000001 | John Doe | Marketing |
| 000002 | Joe Sean | Sales |

So how can I create an insert statement for that data? And because I have 5000 rows data that I want to insert, how to insert it efficiently?

I want to create an insert statement directly because this is just one time, but because there are many data that I need to look to another tables, I think it will take many resources to process that.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You have a text file.  On the client machine or on the server machine?  Can you create an external table/ physical table in the database into which you load the text data?  Can you create a `SQL*Loader` script to load the data?  You've tagged this for SQL Developer so are you trying to use only SQL Developer to load the data?

Answer (score 1):

This example shows how to do it with **external table**.

This is the target table (all data should be inserted here):

```
SQL> desc sales_master
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 AGT_CODE                                           VARCHAR2(6)
 AGT_NAME                                           VARCHAR2(20)
 JOB                                                VARCHAR2(20)
 SALES                                              NUMBER
```

This is table you already have, and it has some data:

```
SQL> select * from agt_info;

AGT_CO AGT_NAME             JOB
------ -------------------- --------------------
000001 John Doe             Marketing
000002 Joe Sean             Sales
```

To be able to work with external tables, you have to talk to DBA to

- create directory - Oracle object which points to directory (folder) which is usually located on a database server, and
- grant privileges (usually `read` and `write`) to user who will be using it

I'm not a DBA and don't have privileges to do so to demonstrate it *live*, but - if you actually are a DBA - this is what you should do. Connect as `SYS` and run the following statements (of course, you'd use your own directory names and your own user):

```
create directory ext_dir as 'c:\temp';
grant read, write on directory ext_dir to scott;
```

Then, connect as user who will load data. In my case, that's `scott`:

```
SQL> show user
USER is "SCOTT"
SQL> select directory_name from all_directories;

DIRECTORY_NAME
------------------------------
EXT_DIR
```

Sample data is stored in `txt_data.txt` file which is in `c:\temp` directory on database server. Its contents is

```
000001,20000
000002,25000
```

Create external table:

```
SQL> create table txt_data
  2    (agt_code   varchar2(6),
  3     sales      varchar2(10)
  4    )
  5  organization external
  6    (type oracle_loader
  7     default directory ext_dir
  8     access parameters
  9       (records delimited by newline
 10        fields terminated by ','
 11        missing field values are null
 12          (agt_code,
 13           sales
 14          )
 15       )
 16     location ('txt_data.txt')
 17    );

Table created.
```

Do I see any data?

```
SQL> select * from txt_data;

AGT_CO SALES
------ ----------
000001 20000
000002 25000
```

OK; the rest is easy: write an `insert` statement that joins data from `agt_info` and `txt_data`:

```
SQL> insert into sales_master (agt_code, agt_name, job, sales)
  2    select t.agt_code, i.agt_name, i.job, to_number(replace(t.sales, chr(13)))
  3    from txt_data t join agt_info i on i.agt_code = t.agt_code;

2 rows created.
```

Final result:

```
SQL> select * from sales_master;

AGT_CO AGT_NAME             JOB                       SALES
------ -------------------- -------------------- ----------
000001 John Doe             Marketing                 20000
000002 Joe Sean             Sales                     25000

SQL>
```

---

Another option is to load data using **SQL*Loader** utility. Its *benefit* is that you can use it on your own computer as it doesn't require Oracle directory so you don't have to contact DBA.

Still connected as `scott`, I'm dropping external table and creating a new one:

```
SQL> drop table txt_data;

Table dropped.

SQL> create table txt_data
  2    (agt_code varchar2(6),
  3     sales    number);

Table created.
```

Sample file is now located in my local directory. Control file, which tells Oracle what to load and how:

```
LOAD DATA
INFILE txt_data.txt
REPLACE
INTO TABLE txt_data
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
agt_code,
sales
)
```

Loading session:

```
SQL> $sqlldr scott/tiger@orcl control=test50.ctl log=test50.log

SQL*Loader: Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production on Uto Ruj 19 08:29:35 2023
Version 18.5.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2018, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Path used:      Conventional
Commit point reached - logical record count 1
Commit point reached - logical record count 2

Table TXT_DATA:
  2 Rows successfully loaded.

Check the log file:
  test50.log
for more information about the load.
```

What's the result?

```
SQL> select * from txt_data;

AGT_CO      SALES
------ ----------
000001      20000
000002      25000
```

Inserting into the target table:

```
SQL> truncate table sales_master;

Table truncated.

SQL> insert into sales_master (agt_code, agt_name, job, sales)
  2    select t.agt_code, i.agt_name, i.job, t.sales
  3    from txt_data t join agt_info i on i.agt_code = t.agt_code;

2 rows created.

SQL> select * from sales_master;

AGT_CO AGT_NAME             JOB                       SALES
------ -------------------- -------------------- ----------
000001 John Doe             Marketing                 20000
000002 Joe Sean             Sales                     25000

SQL>
```